# Change/add Class of menu li to "active" Based on specific URLs

Tags: jquery, html

I have a navigation menu with `li`'s that link to many pages with different urls. How do I change the class `.has-sub` to `.active` for a navigation menu based on URL of the page displayed? So anytime a page that is under this nav of "Galleries"  is loaded, the nav link is "active".

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='http://www.example.com/' id="HOME">Home</a></li>   
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='http://www.example.com/galleries.html' id="GALLERIES">GALLERIES</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='http://www.example.com/color.html'>Color</a></li>
         <li><a href='http://www.example.com/product-gallery.html'>Product</a></li>
         <li><a href='http://www.example.com/galleries/other/index.html'>Other</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li> 
</ul>
```

I have no idea what to use for jquery.

Comment: your example url doesn't seem to be in the right format. Do you mean http://www.example.com/Home.html ?

Comment: You'll need a back-end solution to apply the class, or you'll need some JavaScript to do URL parsing. There are many examples on SO.